# Ubuntu 23.04 won't boot/black screen into GUI Dell PowerEdge 2900

Tags: boot

So I Installed Ubuntu GUI on my PowerEdge 2900, installed it via USB media, it installed just fine. Then after rebooting the system, Ubuntu OS would go boot a load screen (during boot process) then cuts black, monitor displayed message that no VGA signal is found. I believe it may be a Display Driver issue as I booted into recovery mode and I was able to get the CLI prompt on my screen, Just that going into the actual desktop doesn't work. Tried a reinstall, Boot-Repair (The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. Please change it to EFI mode. Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit, Older system doesn't have UEFI..).

I'm not sure what else to try..any help would be appreciated.